# find is missing a result -- how is that possible?

Tags: files, find

What conditions explain this output:

```
root@ip:/# find / -name "server.xml" -print
/etc/tomcat7/server.xml
root@ip:/# ls /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/server.xml 
/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/server.xml
```

I am running this as root, and starting the find from the root directory.  I don't understand why the file I show with the "ls" command isn't coming up in the results.

#### Edit

output of `mount`:

```
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

And:

```
root@ip:/# ls -la /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/
total 196
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root      4096 Apr 29 03:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 95 root root      4096 Apr 29 04:23 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 root tomcat7   4096 Apr 29 03:22 Catalina
-rw-r--r--  1 root tomcat7   5586 Apr  1 20:32 catalina.properties
-rw-r--r--  1 root tomcat7   1394 Feb 25  2012 context.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 root tomcat7   2370 Jul 12  2012 logging.properties
drwxr-xr-x  2 root tomcat7   4096 Apr 29 03:22 policy.d
-rw-r--r--  1 root tomcat7   6500 Apr  1 20:32 server.xml
-rw-r-----  1 root tomcat7   1530 Feb 25  2012 tomcat-users.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 root tomcat7 152716 Feb 25  2012 web.xml
```

And:

```
root@ip-:/# ls -la /var/lib/tomcat7
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 root    root    4096 Apr 29 03:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 40 root    root    4096 Apr 29 01:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Apr 29 03:22 common
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      12 Apr  1 20:32 conf -> /etc/tomcat7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      17 Apr  1 20:32 logs -> ../../log/tomcat7
drwxr-xr-x  3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Apr 29 03:22 server
drwxr-xr-x  3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Apr 29 03:22 shared
drwxrwxr-x  4 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Apr 29 04:20 webapps
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      19 Apr  1 20:32 work -> ../../cache/tomcat7
```

Comment: Is /var a different partition? Are there any special mount parameters? You might want to post the output of "ls -la /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/" and "mount" - it might help the case, not sure though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would happen if `/var/lib/tomcat7/conf` is a symbolic link to `/etc/tomcat7`.

By default, `find` (the coreutils version anyway) will not follow symlinks. Try with the `-L` flag:

```
find -L / -name "server.xml" -print
```

Comment: hmm... i get an infinite loop when i run with -L.  fwiw, if i do "ls -l" inside of /etc/, tomcat7 is not listed as a link, but as an ordinary directory.  or am i misunderstanding you?

Comment: That's strange. What about `ls -l /var/lib/` and `var/lib/tomcat7`?

Comment: Ah, ok, the tomcat7 one is culprit, correct?

Comment: Ah! I had misread your question - thought find returned the path in /var/lib. Yes, that symlink is the reason. Still, I don't see a reason for a loop.